# Write a method that will return a list of all #s in the matrix that repeat. Numbers should be placed in the list once it is determined they repeat

Tags: java, matrix

Sample Cases

go( [ 1, 2, 3, 0 ] , [ 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 ] )  should return [1, 0]

go( [ 1, 2, 3, 0 ] , [ 0, 1, 0, 1, 1 ] )  should return [0, 1]

go( [ 4, 15, 1 ] , [ 73, 2 ] ) should return []

go( [ 7, 7, 7 ], [ -12, 30 ] , [ 0 ] )  should return [7]

My Code:`

```
List<Integer> go( int[][] mat ) 
{
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++)
    {
      for(int j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++)
      {
        if(mat[i][j] == mat[i + 1][j + 1])
        {
          list.add(mat[i][j]);
        }
      }
    }
    return list;
}`
```

Idk how to do this, that was my attempt im getting out of bounds errors

Comment: Please describe the input data format a bit better - `int [][]` doesn't seem the best way to do this. Anyway, my algorithm would be to have two sets, one of numbers found, and one of duplicates. For each number in the input, if it already exists in the numbers found set, add it to the duplicates set, otherwise add it to the numbers found set.

Comment: You loop until the last element, and then you try to check the value of the element after that, of course that will give an out-of-bounds exception.